# Jetty upgrade throwing exception after upgrading to 9.4.43.v20210629

Tags: java, maven, jetty, initializer

My project is using Jetty(org.eclipse.jetty) jars and I have upgraded it from 9.4.33 to latest 9.4.43
Post upgrade when I tried to start the services it is throwing the exception of

```
Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@1e461e41{/,file:///opt/company/Myserver/src/main/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{src/main/webapp}
java.lang.noclassdeffounderror org/apache/jasper/servlet/jasperinitializer
```

Can anybody help me what exactly I am missing here. I double checked to ensure concern jars are available.
What I could figure out so far its reading the class at compile time but not able to find it at run time thus seeing this exception.

I tried replacing the 9.4.43 jars again with 9.4.33 and it worked fine without any other config/code change.

Any leads would be appreciated on how to trace and fix this issue.

Comment: Make sure you don't have JSP implementation jars in your `WEB-INF/lib`

Comment: There is really not enough information here to render a solution.  Please edit your question and include the details of how you start Jetty, if you are using jetty-home/jetty-base, the `--list-config` output, and also what jars you have in your `WEB-INF/lib` on your webapp.

Comment: All the jars are kept in the "/opt/company/Myserver/lib" folder.  
There is just web.xml file kept in the WEB-INF directory.

Project is using following jetty:

jetty-annotations    
jetty-io     
jetty-security  
 jetty-util-ajax 
jetty-continuation   
jetty-jndi   
jetty-server     
jetty-webapp 
jetty-deploy         
jetty-plus   
jetty-servlet    
jetty-xml 
jetty-http           
 jetty-util